# NodeJs ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, ejs

when i try to render a page in NodeJs i get this error, what im trying to do is

1. The user submit the form which is working perfectly fine
2. Show loading page, res.render("loading")
3. After the process done in server, i need it to go to another page, with parameters

i also tried `res.redirect('/');`
i googled a lot of solutions nothing worked, and i'm still beginner in NodeJs

i'm using

```
"body-parser": "^1.18.3",
"consolidate": "^0.15.1",
"ejs": "^2.6.1",
"express": "^4.16.4",
```

The Error

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:526:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/root/payment/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/root/payment/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at done (/root/payment/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:10)
    at /root/payment/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:645:7
    at /root/payment/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:161:5
    at Promise._execute (/root/payment/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:384:9)
    at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/root/payment/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:518:18)
    at new Promise (/root/payment/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:103:10)
    at promisify (/root/payment/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:154:10)
    at Function.exports.ejs.render (/root/payment/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:641:10)
    at /root/payment/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:181:27
    at /root/payment/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:101:5
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:63:3)
```

the code

```
app.post("/pay", (req, res) => {
    res.render("loading");
    doPayPalOut(req, res)
});

async function doPayPalOut(req, res) {

    {... }
    await paypal.payout.create(create_payout_json, function (error, payout) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("==========", error.response);
            // throw error;
        } else {
            res.render('/success', { pdet: payout });
        }
    });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because you're calling `res.render()` more than once for the same response. Once you call it the first time, response headers will be sent to the client and you can't call it again.

If you really want to have some kind of "loading" message then you should implement it on the client with JavaScript, not on the server.

Comment: Yes, but what if i wanted to take user to another page ? is that possible ?

Comment: You can only send one response for each request from the client, so no matter which response method you use (`res.render()`, `res.redirect()`, `res.send()`, etc.), you can only use it once.

So yes, you can call `res.redirect()` to take the user to another page from the one that was requested, but if you do that then you can't call `res.render()` or any of the other response methods.

Answer (score -1):

If you have to implement it on the server side, you can use the long link method: SSE([Server sent events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events)), WS([web socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)), [bigpipe](http://www.searchtb.com/2011/04/an-introduction-to-bigpipe.htmljavascri)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).